# Serialize objects with map and circular references in the browser (like v8.serialize in node.js)

Tags: javascript, json

I want to serialize some object. There is Map or some other types which cannot been serialized with `JSON.stringify`:

```js
JSON.stringify({x:new Map([[1,"some value"]])}) // output: '{"x":{}}'
```

I tried to use `bson`, but if key the type of the key is `number`, will throw an error.

In addition, this object may have circular references.

I found in node.js, `v8.serialize()` API can solve my problem, I wonder if there are any alternatives in the browser environment.